# fast radial blur in ios

Tags: ios, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es

I want to do a shine effects in iOS ,looks like this

[image]

I found a radial blur algorithm in OpenCV (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699826/6545468)
 ,and the result was not very satisfactory

[image]

light beam is "discrete",the final outcome depends on  Iterations of `remap`(zoom)，that time consuming.
And I also found some OpenGL Shaders，just similar implementations.

So,is there any way to implement After Effects CC Radial Fast Blur in iOS App(smooth and fast)?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the top image I would say you have no way of doing that fast on a general image by no means. Though this really depends on the image size and your definition of "fast" so lets say that it would be a challenge to draw this under 1 second on an image of size 1024x1024.

For a general image you will have 2 procedures:

First is to redraw the faded image `N` times to canvas where `N` is a number of pixels that the largest effect offset has. On the top image that means insane 200 redraws. If you have some system of openGL you could try and test how long would it take to draw this many samples (without any effect, just redraw to a texture) and if you get near desired result you could try to implement the actual logic...

The second is fetching the surrounding relevant samples for each fragment (pixel) which is the most used procedure for the gaussian blur. This procedure usually uses a matrix of pixels in range from 7x7 to 11x11 and is still a slow and heavy operation and the effect is not very blurry on large images. In your case we are looking at about 200x200 samples again which is a total NO-NO, I wouldn't even bother trying it.

Things may get interesting if you try to combine the 2 procedures. You could try to blur the input image first with the second procedure which will effectively enlarge the objects by a few pixels. Then you can (just for the shine) redraw the blurred image using the first procedure with reduced number of samples. For instance if the size of the blur is about 5 pixels then you might be able to reduce the number of redraws 2-3 times which may be quite a performance gain. This procedure will not make the effect as sharp as on the image you are having though but you are in luck here: The second image you posted already does exactly what you need to test this. Simply create a blurred version of the image you are already using and test how many samples are needed to get a nice result.

There are still quite a few possible optimizations which may or may not impact the quality of the effect. If you are doing a gaussian blur it is usually safe to down-sample the image a bit. A scale of 2 per dimension reduces the number of fragments by 4 and is surely something to try. I would try the following:

- Draw the image to down-sampled buffer directly applying a gaussian blur using linear mode on the texture
- Redraw some N samples for the shine effect on the down-sampled buffer
- Redraw the result to the up-sampled buffer (original size) applying some gaussian blur again
- Draw the original image over the resulting shadow

If you will be doing any of these make sure to keep the track of the performance. After you are done it would be nice if you shared the results (even if you fail).